# How to add number and special characters?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm very new to SharePoint and currently doing a training project in SharePoint 2013. I need to have a controlled document. So I need to create a column which have a special character and numbers only as shown below. 
I'm not sure on how to do that. Please assist.

```
0942-6479
49288-0630
42507-072
68788-9537
0378-8888
68084-181
42914-001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of tests you can do

#### Test for a valid number by taking out the dash:

```
=ISNUMBER(VALUE(REPLACE(ProdCode,FIND("-",ProdCode),1,"")))
```

#### Test if the dash is at position 4, 5 or 6:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(CHOOSE(7-FIND("-",ProdCode),5,4,3)))
```

*5,4,3 are only placeholders to make CHOOSE return **A** value.. you can write anything:*

```
=NOT(ISERROR(CHOOSE(7-FIND("-",ProdCode),TRUE,"placeholder",FALSE)))
```

#### Test if the length after the dash is 3,4 or 5 characters

```
=NOT(ISERROR(CHOOSE(6-LEN(RIGHT(ProdCode,LEN(ProdCode)-FIND("-",ProdCode))),5,4,3)))
```

### all in one:

```
=AND(
   ISNUMBER(VALUE(REPLACE(ProdCode,FIND("-",ProdCode),1,"")))
  ,NOT(ISERROR(CHOOSE(7-FIND("-",ProdCode),5,4,3)))
  ,NOT(ISERROR(CHOOSE(6-LEN(RIGHT(ProdCode,LEN(ProdCode)-FIND("-",ProdCode))),5,4,3)))
)
```

You probably need more to test edge cases

Comment: Hi Danny.. Thanks for the answer.. How to check whether the length before the dash 3,4, and 5 characters as well? because the length of the  numbers changing before and after the dash.. Hope you can help out..

Comment: Hi Danny.. Please ignore the previous comment.. The formula works perfectly.. really appreciate your help..

Comment: tnx, use the checkmark to mark the answer so it doesn't pop up on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

In your column setting you can find "Column Validation". By type in your validation formula you can enforce your rule and prompt warning message if not match.

You can refer to [this article](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-validate-strict-text-formats-in-sharepoint-2010/) to setup validation rules. Your pattern is a little bit complex. Here is a sample check against DDD-DDD (D for digit):

```
=AND(
(MID([PrdCode],4,1)="-"),
(
(CODE(MID([PrdCode],1,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],1,1))>58)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],2,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],2,1))>58)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],3,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],3,1))>58)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],5,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],5,1))>58)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],6,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],6,1))>58)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],7,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID([PrdCode],7,1))>58)
=6
),
(LEN([PrdCode])=7))
```

You may simply repeat above pattern for 8 more times and combine with "OR". Or you may think of other clever way.

If you want to use regular expression, it is not supported in OOTB SharePoint. But you can apply a JQuery library or modify your form with [MS InfoPath](http://3sharp.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-in-sharepoint-lists/).

Comment: Hi Mark 

Thanks for the quick reply.
The numbers are not on the same scale. Thus I have problem creating the formula. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Can you tell what exactly is the pattern? First part 4-5 characters, second part 3-4?

Comment: Actually it's Product Code column.. 
The patterns are 3-3, 3-4, 3-5, 4-3, 4-4, 4-5, 5-3, 5-4, 5-5

Comment: I updated my answer for an example. Maybe able to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. I will try out and I have MS InfoPath as well. maybe if you are free you can guide me on that.. sorry to trouble you..

Comment: Hi Mark.. is it possible to e-mail you what I have done MS InfoPath validation for clear understanding and maybe you can guide me through that? I'm still unable to get the correct validation.

Comment: Sorry I don't have infopath experience. It is out of my company budget T_T